# %CommonDir% Errors after modifying of Visual Studio 15 with tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have modified Visual Studio 2015 with [tools for Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/) and now when I'm trying to load any project I have set of errors, and enable to load VS project

> with the file %CommonDir%\dte80 could not be loaded. Attempt to
>   repair this condition failed because the file not be found

then under the same %CommonDir%:

```
dte80.olb
dte90.olb 
dte90a.olb 
vslangproj80.olb 
vslangproj90.olb 
vsmos.olb
```

I can't load project.

What can I do to find out from this situation. I have to reinstall VS can it solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have already installed a newer version of Microsoft Visual C++. If you uninstall the 2017 version of this, you will have no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by installing "Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell" downloaded from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads. You need to sign up for their free developer program before you can search for old downloads.

Comment: Dude, you just saved me from having to start over from scratch installing/configuring a new dev pc (after I had installed visual studio community 2017 and then uninstalled that and installed visual studio community 2015 in order to accommodate a large, major asp.net webforms project for a client)!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you sooooo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem :-
Go to control panel Uninstall C++ 2015 and above.
Now open Visual Studio 2015 installer then click on repair option.
Now restart and run. It worked for me you can also try.